# There is no GPU Utilization on AWS SageMaker pytorch-training:1.11.0-gpu-py38-cu113-ubuntu20.04-sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, gpu, amazon-sagemaker, training-data

I'm running the ML training on AWS Sagemaker through the step-function and the step-function takes an ECR docker GPU image to run the ML Training job, but the training job is not using the GPU.

Training Instance Type = "ml.p3.2xlarge"

[DockerFile source:](https://github.com/aws/deep-learning-containers/blob/master/huggingface/pytorch/training/docker/1.11/py3/cu113/Dockerfile.trcomp.gpu)

[image: Instance Metrics]

I've been trying to run the Training job on the GPU instance but the training job isn't utilizing the GPU, the job just uses the CPU, so if anyone face the same issue please guide, Thanks.

The following command returns "True":

```
import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

Comment: Can you upload your training code? It seems to be a problem external to sagemaker.

Comment: Can you upload a version of the training script will be difficult to tell without looking at the setup